# Setting up Anaconda with Pycharm errors

Tags: python, import, pycharm, anaconda, python-3.7

I've spent the greater part of my day trying to set up pycharm on my new computer.

http://courses.cse.tamu.edu/keyser/engr102/InstallInstructions.pdf

I've followed the instructions listed here to the T. These were the original instructions given to me when I first installed it and I don't remember having any issues. I wanted to load some of my older scripts on it to make sure it worked and knew I would have to import some of the old packages again; however, I don't seem to be able to import any packages at all. I also noticed that pyautogui isn't importing which should be included in the pycharm library? Trying to manually import it doesn't work either. This set of instructions has me set up a Virualenv environment instead of a conda environment and, doing this before, I still had the option in packages to use the conda package manager which i don't have when setting it up in this way now. All in all I seem to be missing a ton of packages and am completely unable to install new ones. At this rate I can't run a single one of my more complex scripts without the ability to import packages and i'm in a pretty tight spot. Thanks in advance for you time and help.

Answer (score 0):

I use Anaconda with PyCharm without any issues, I took a brief look at the instructions linked, where are you getting stuck?  Do you already have Anaconda installed?  You should try to launch the Anaconda prompt and see that it works.  You can click start, then search for anaconda prompt and launch it.  If that's successful, then you can either create an environment inside Anaconda prompt and then pull that environment into PyCharm or you can create an environment from within Pycharm--either is fine.

Have you seen the instructions here? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/conda-support-creating-conda-virtual-environment.html

If you need better instructions than that then you're going to have to explain where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: The anaconda prompt works, and i can write scripts in pycharm. Trying to install packages (that many of my scripts have dependencies on) returns the following: [link](https://imgur.com/a/beJAfqJ)